# Gerar gráfico no Excel - C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, gráfico

Olá, gostaria de tirar uma dúvida: estou exportando os dados gerados em um gridview para o Excel, e, ao mesmo tempo estou gerando um Gráfico no próprio Excel a partir do C#. Eu gostaria que o tamanho do gráfico aumentasse dinamicamente de acordo com o tamanho do range. Atualmente está definido de forma estática.

Código da geração do gráfico:

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObjects)xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
```

/*DEFINIR TAMANHO DO GRÁFICO*/ Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(20, 160, 600, 500);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;

/*RANGE PARA GERAÇÃO DO GRÁFICO*/ CR = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("C:C","D:D");
            chartPage.SetSourceData(CR, misValue);
            chartPage.ChartType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlChartType.xlColumnClustered;

}

Por favor poderiam me ajudar?